# Find block number of a table in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have created a table in a separate tablespace in an Oracle database. Is there a way using the v$ views or any other method to find the starting block number of the table in the given page and tablespace?

I used v$datafile to determine the page number and tablespace number in the given database. Now, I need to find the block number of the given table in the tablespace!

Any suggestions would be of great help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the `dba_extents` table:

```
select owner, segment_name, tablespace_name, file_id, block_id
from dba_extents
where segment_name = 'FND_USER';
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I could retrieve the block details using dba_segments as well!